# Pushbutton works intermittently (Arduino)

Tags: button, arduino, led

I'm playing with Arduino and I've tried a [simple circuit](https://circuits.io/circuits/5769971-push-button-and-an-led) where an LED lights up when you press a [pushbutton](https://www.indiamart.com/tantia-electronic/micro-switches-gilard-lema.html), using the `attachInterrupt()` function.

Here is the code:

```
const byte LED = 11;
const byte Pushbutton = 2;

// run setup code

void setup() {
  pinMode(Pushbutton, INPUT);
  pinMode(LED, OUTPUT);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(Pushbutton), LEDManager, CHANGE);
}

void loop() {}

// <summary>LED manager HIGH or LOW</summary>
void LEDManager() {
  digitalWrite(LED, digitalRead(Pushbutton));
}
```

My circuit works but intermittently or when I touch the wire connected to pin `D2`.

I don't understand why and I need some help!

## Update

I've tried many configurations and when I use new wires it works! The problem was welds, they were not well done and had probably damaged the wires (my soldering iron was too hot).

*(Spoiler, a new fail! Wow!)*

## Update 2!

This time, I changed the circuit and connected pin `D2` to the `COM` port of the pushbutton. The `COM` port is connected to a 10k ohm resistor that is connected to the Gnd pin and 3.3V pin is connected to the ON port of the pushbutton (I was inspired by [that](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Debounce), *thanks ingo*).

It's finally working, alleluia !

Comment: where is your digitalWrite(Pushbutton,HIGH) in your setup block?

Comment: Search for 'debounce' either hardware or software. Your button bounces and makes contact more than once

Comment: Zharios : the digitalWrite is in the LEDManager function
ingo : i will try :)

Comment: nope, sorry ingo, your solution doesn't work

Comment: @CeciSembleAbsurde. If you put CHANGE in the interruptio, you thorw one when you push the button and other when you release the button. Change flag by RISING or FALLING.

Comment: update ! i've found the solution, thanks guys ! (up helpers :) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed the circuit and connected pin `D2` to the `COM` port of the pushbutton. The `COM` port is connected to a 10k ohm resistor that is connected to the Gnd pin and 3.3V pin is connected to the ON port of the pushbutton (I was inspired by [that](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Debounce), *thanks ingo*).